# React JSX compiling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add the class name "active" to links when they are clicked. I can't get this JSX to compile.

```
      <li onClick={this.showDeals}><a className={(this.props.panel == 'deals') ? 'active' : ''>Deals</a></li>
      <li onClick={this.showTasks}><a className={(this.props.panel == 'tasks') ? 'active' : ''>Tasks</a></li>
      <li onClick={this.showActivities}><a className={(this.props.panel == 'activities') ? 'active' : ''>Activities</a></li>
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
ReactifyError: content.js: Parse Error: Line 740: Invalid regular expression while parsing file
```

Comment: You're missing the closing `}` on the className prop for each.

Comment: Dang! Thanks. I shouldn't known it was something stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close your `className={...` 's.